# std::for_each and functors - what signatures can operator() have?

Tags: c++, foreach, functor

I want to use a `std::for_each` call to loop through some values and invoke a functor to map the value to a string, and return that value to the `for_each`, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct myfunctor
{
    myfunctor(map<int, string>& x) : mymap(x) {
        cout << "Inside myfunctor ctor" << endl;
    };

    map<int, string>& mymap;

    string operator()(int mapthis)
    {
        cout << "Inside myfunctor operator(" << mapthis << ")" << endl;
        return mymap[mapthis];
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<int, string> codes { {1, "abel"}, {2, "baker"}, {3, "charlie"} };

    cout << "Main() - construct myfunctor" << endl;
    myfunctor t(codes);

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

    string blah;
    cout << "Main() - begin for_each" << endl;
    std::for_each(arr, arr+2, blah.append(t));
    cout << blah << endl;
}
```

It doesn't compile because it can't convert from a `myfunctor` to a `string`.  But even if it did, is it legal to return something from `operator()`, to be applied by the `for_each` as I'm trying to do?  Is it possible to pass other parameters to `operator()` besides the implied range variable of the `for_each`?

If it is possible for `operator()` to have a return value, how would I write a myfunctor-to-string conversion method?

I;ve just never seen examples of anything other than `void operator()(SingleArgument)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to pass your functor to `std::for_each` as a third argument. You are passing the result of the function call `blah.append(t)`. Also, the functor is the thing that is supposed to do *all* the work during the `for_each`, so you'll have to shift the call to `append` to inside the `operator()`. Easiest way: just pass your string as a reference.

```
struct myfunctor
{
    myfunctor( string& toAppend, map<int, string>& x ) : appendage(toAppend), mymap( x ) {
        cout << "Inside myfunctor ctor" << endl;
    };

    map<int, string>& mymap;
    string& appendage;

    void operator()(int mapthis)
    {
        cout << "Inside myfunctor operator(" << mapthis << ")" << endl;
        appendage.append( mymap[mapthis] );
            //std::for_each will not use a return value of this function for anything
    }
};

void main2()
{
    map<int, string> codes { {1, "abel"}, { 2, "baker" }, { 3, "charlie" } };

    cout << "Main() - construct myfunctor" << endl;


    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    string blah;
    myfunctor t( blah, codes ); //Pass in blah so the functor can append to it.
    cout << "Main() - begin for_each" << endl;
    std::for_each( arr, arr + 3, t ); //arr+3 to loop over all 3 elems of arr
    cout << blah << endl;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Am I correct in understanding that idea here is that the third param to for_each is an *object*, and not really a function call?

Comment: @chap it is an object which `operator()` is defined, and `()` will be repeatedly invoked by `for_each` with the elements of the range.  Note that function pointers qualify if the signature matches.